# Cancel HTML in a shortcode

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

What I am trying to do is to insert an icon into a text widget in wordpress.

Code:

```
[icons border_radius="0" align="center" size="large" style="style1" icon_c="#ffffff" icon_bgc="" icon_c_hover="#ffffff" icon_bgc_hover=""]    
[single_icon icon="27|fontawesome"]    
[/icons]
&nbsp;<h5 style="text-align: center;">Kęstučio g. 4, Vilnius</h5>
```

Result:
[image]

But the problem is, the icon (the globe) gets anchored. The "a" tags appear and it leads to the same page. Is there any way to cancel the HTML that is somehow applied ?

Comment: Do you use wordpress plugin for creating shortcode? What is the plugin?

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. There is no plugin, this shortcode is integrated in the "Arena" theme.